# Know offset of a div placed after lazy load images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div wrapper in which lazy load images are present. Then I have a div below those images and I want to make it Sticky.

```
<div id="someWrapper">
    <img class="lazy" data-original="someImageURL"></img>
    <img class="lazy" data-original="someImageURL"></img>
   <img class="lazy" data-original="someImageURL"></img>
   <img class="lazy" data-original="someImageURL"></img>
   <div class="sticky">SomeContents</div> <!-- want to make this sticky on scrool -->
</div>
```

In order to make them sticky I need offset of the div. Problem is offset is not fixed on the page because of lazy load images that keep pushing the div downward. Image heights are unknown. No of images are 4. Tried using appear event on the last load element but its not giving me accurate results. Please help me how to solve this problem. I want to get offset of the sticky div so I can make a check on the scroll event.

Comment: when are the images loaded?

Comment: And what is `someImageURL`? a placeholder image or actual image?

Comment: Can you upload the image of layout that you are expecting ?

Comment: May be you need an image loader to see if the last image is loaded. When loaded, check for the div offset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing around and some research achieved the desired like this:

```
function activateStickyScrollEvent(offSetValue){
//code to activate scroll event

}

var lazyLength=$('#someWrapper lazy').length;
var lazyCount=0;
$('#someWrapper lazy').one('appear',function(){
      ++lazyCount;
      if(lazyCount===lazyLength){
         var getWrapperOffset=$('#someWrapper').offSet().top;
         activateStickyScrollEvent(getWrapperOffset);

})
```

Answer (score 0):

So, as I said, you may have to check if the last image in the set has been loaded, and then check for the element's offset. Here is a demo of how it could be done. Feel free to adapt the code to suit your needs.

```js
//Ref to the wrapper
var $wrapper = $("#someWrapper");
//Ref to the last image in the set
var lastImgSrc = $wrapper.find(" > img:last").attr("data-original");

var image = new Image();
image.onload = function () {
    //do something on load...
    var offset = $wrapper.find(".sticky").offset();
    alert (offset.top);
}
image.onerror = function () {
   //do something on error...
}
image.src = lastImgSrc;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="someWrapper">
    <img class="lazy" data-original="someImageURL" />
    <img class="lazy" data-original="someImageURL" />
    <img class="lazy" data-original="http://dreamatico.com/data_images/sea/sea-4.jpg" src="http://dreamatico.com/data_images/sea/sea-4.jpg" width="100%" />
    <img class="lazy" data-original="http://dreamatico.com/data_images/sea/sea-3.jpg" src="http://dreamatico.com/data_images/sea/sea-3.jpg" width="100%" />
    <div class="sticky">SomeContents</div> <!-- want to make this sticky on scrool -->
</div>
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can count images to load, and the get the offset (OFFSET in my example) :

```
$(function() {

    function imageLoaded() {
       counter--; 
       if( counter === 0 ) {
           //  Here All your "lazy" images are loaded
           var OFFSET = $('#someWrapper').offset().top;  <---- you can get offset 
       }
    }

    var images = $('.lazy'),
        counter = images.length;  // initialize the counter

    images.each(function() {
        if( this.complete ) {
            imageLoaded.call( this );
        } else {
            $(this).one('load', imageLoaded);
        }
    });
});
```